# puclish messeage to arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , I'm trying to move  robot using ROS & arduino. I confirmed message "twist_cmd" published  using echo but I don't know how to send the message to arduino. Please tell me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270950/puclish-messeage-to-arduino/) by [shibaneko](https://answers.ros.org/users/31912/shibaneko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please See rosserial_arduino. There are an couple of Tutorials explaining what you need:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1